# Xfce not taking up full width of display on Xubuntu

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, lightdm

I'm having this problem I can simply only describe visually, like so:

[image: malfunctioning Xfce display]

Googling the error came to nothing. lightdm also exhibits this behavior but switches back and forth from this to the proper display as I click on things. I remember cleaning out lightdm entirely and reinstalling it but this problem came back again. If I launch LXDE this doesn't happen but I want to keep using Xfce. How can I fix this?

Comment: Open a terminal and run xrandr.
Does it show your "normal" resolution on the options?

Comment: I tried xrandr and it didn't work. Had to nuke the installation from orbit.

Comment: Wait, you tried setting the proper config with xrandr? Or did you just run ```xrandr``` and looked for the "normal" res on the output?

Comment: And by "nuke the installation", do you mean you just reinstalled the whole OS?

Comment: Correct. I may never find out what the real problem was.